# How to send current page in Google Chrome to Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome

In Firefox I use a add-on called "Open With" which adds Chrome and Safari icons in Firefox's toolbar. If I want to open the current webpage in Firefox in one of these browsers, I just click that button and the page opens in the chosen browser in a new tab.

I would like similar functionality but in Google Chrome, to be able to send current page to other browsers, mainly to Firefox.

Does anyone know a way or a extension?

Answer (score 1):

In the URL box in Chrome on the left is an icon, sheet of paper.   Drag the icon to the firefox window and drop it.
The reverse also works.

If the firefox window is hidden or underneath Chrome then drag the icon to the Taskbar and over the Firefox icon, hold it for a split second and the Firefox window will be brought to the front.  Then drop the icon into Firefox.

No extension that I've found yet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I ended up buying Choosy. It adds a button in Chrome's toolbar which when clicked, brings up a list of browsers (that I can configure) and selecting a browser launches the current page in that browser.